# How to use procedureType in schema of SurgicalProcedure type?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The type `MedicalProcedureType` is minimally noninvasive.
How should the code be added?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "SurgicalProcedure",
    "name": "Intragastric Balloon",
    "url": "https://obesityasia.com/intragastric-balloon/",
    "image": "https://obesityasia.com/images/1.-Intra-Gastric-Ballon-1.jpg",
    "bodyLocation":"Stomach",
    "procedureType":{
        "@type":"MedicalProcedureType",
        
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of the [`procedureType`](https://schema.org/procedureType) property is an instance of the class [`MedicalProcedureType`](https://schema.org/MedicalProcedureType). Schema.org currently defines two such instances ([`NoninvasiveProcedure`](https://schema.org/NoninvasiveProcedure), [`PercutaneousProcedure`](https://schema.org/PercutaneousProcedure)).

JSON-LD example:

```json
"procedureType": { "@id": "http://schema.org/NoninvasiveProcedure" }
```

By using `@id` here, it gets conveyed that the value is an IRI. This is not necessary for your use of `url` and `image`, because [Schema.org’s JSON-LD context](https://schema.org/docs/jsonldcontext.json) defines that already for these properties, but not for `procedureType`.

Comment: ```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "SurgicalProcedure",
    "name": "Intragastric Balloon",
    "url": "https://obesityasia.com/intragastric-balloon/",
    "image": "https://obesityasia.com/images/1.-Intra-Gastric-Ballon-1.jpg",
    "bodyLocation":"Stomach",
     "procedureType": { 
                 "@id": "http://schema.org/NoninvasiveProcedure"
       }
}
</script>
```

So, is this the final code?

Comment: @ssc1234: Yes, only the value for `procedureType` changed.